# Comparing string array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have the following code within a for loop to see if a string equals a search string:

```
if(Data.coord[i].equals(Data.search))
```

I've tested the code with exact values i.e if 1=1 and the rest of the code works fine. It just doesn't like the string comparison. The consol gives out this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at highercoursework.Search.main(Search.java:16)
at highercoursework.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Thanks

Comment: Restart in Debug Mode and set a breakpoint.

Comment: The array is initialized in a data class: static String[] coord = new String[100]; However if no data is needed for that array its just stored as a null value.

Comment: Are you sure i is a valid key for `Data.coord[]`?

Comment: I suggest splitting this row into separate ones so that you can debug this issue from the logs. The nullpointer can be the Data.coord or the Data.coord[i] or even Data.search.

the other things is to debug

Comment: seems like your String array is not initialised

Answer (score 2):

You have an unpopulated element in your array i.e.

```
Data.coord[i]
```

is `null`. Note that Data.search could be null, but the `equals()` method will handle this. You just need to perform the lement check first.

Comment: Ahh right, I can't think of a way to avoid this. I could do to ifs first to check if values are null and then only compare none null values?

Comment: Nope you should call `equals()` on an object you know it exists thus using the form in my answer. This is considered a good practice when comparing objects. Always call `equals()` on the object you already know is not null if possible.

Comment: i think @AdamArold is absolutely correct , logically it saves you the trouble plus avoids your exception , this is more appropriate approach

Answer (score 2):

You should compare the constant to your parameter since it can be `null`.

For example if `Data.search` is a constant which you are searching for you should do this:

```
if(Data.search.equals(Data.coord[i]))
```

In this case you won't end up trying to call methods on a `null` reference and you won't need unnecessary `null` checks either.

Comment: In that case he has to null check one. But in this case we know that `Data.search` is a constant.

Comment: Do we *know* that ? I'm not sure that's explicit (it looks to me like a user input value or similar)

Comment: I assumed it from the context. May be it is null but I really don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] coord = new String[100];
```

This will mean you can assign something to coord[0] but until you do that coord[0] is null. Hence the null pointer exception.

You can try.

```
String data= Data.coord[i];
if(data != null && data.equals(Data.search))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid your problem in two ways:

- In the case coord[i] should not be null

  ```
  if (Data.coord[i] != null) {
      if(Data.coord[i].equals(Data.search)) {

      }
  } else {
      logger.error("Unexpected Behavior: coord[i] should not be null");
  }
  ```

Note: You can replace the logger message by a more appropriated code that fit to your requirement.

---

- In the case your your coord[i] can be null

comparing in this way won't throw an exception if Data.coord[i] is null. (Assuming Data.search is a constant and can't bu null) So the rules for this case is: use in priority a String object constant to call the method equals.

```
if (Data.search.equals(Data.coord[i])) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(DATA != null && Data.coord[i].equals(Data.search))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this to understand [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

if coord[] is initialized properly, value of `Data.coord[i]` may be null. You can check

```
if(Data.coord[i] != null && Data.coord[i].equals(Data.search)) {}
```